# Safari weird behaviour on hovering menu elements

Tags: css, safari

I'm facing some issues only with Safari, where in a regular menu dropdown, the 2nd level drop won't disappear after mouse left the panel.

The menu structure is standard:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>Item</a></li>
   <li>
     <a>Item</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a>Item</a></li>
         <li>
         <a>Item</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a>Item</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The css: 
ul li:hover .sub-menu { display:block; }

When mouse leaves the 2nd level Safari keeps showing it and when I inspect is not even showing like an element. Also, as soon as I click on ANY css property, menu will disappear.

I uploaded a video to show you the problem:

https://youtu.be/0vBIyEo09rM

Comment: Can you make a working jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Hi, I will, but please make sure to watch the video.